# excluding subpattern from regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a JS app that's triggering "Republic of the Congo" when I'm entering "Democratic Republic of the Congo". How can I tell my `/republic\s*of\s*the\s*congo/i` regex not to trigger upon inclusion of the string "democratic"?

`\b` doesn't work because "democratic" is separated by a white space.

Comment: Don't forget to specify the language/program you use. Many flavors of regex don't have negative look behind for example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add boundaries to the regex as

```
/^republic\s*of\s*the\s*congo$/i
```

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string.
- `$` Anchors the regex at the end of the string

These anchors ensure that there is nothing presceded or followed by `Republic of the Congo`.

---

Now if your regex supports negative look behind, you can also write it as

```
/(?<!democratic)\s*republic\s*of\s*the\s*congo/i
```

- `(?<!democratic)` Asserts that the `Republic of the Congo` is not presceded by `democratic`